# How to align image same as text in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Look at the following picture:

[image]

This is Word 2007. `hello/world` is a MathType formula; the second formula is an image.

I want the image to be treated exactly the same as the MathType formula, specifically the way it is aligned vertically on the same level as the text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to this article on [Vertical Alignment of an Inline Graphic](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T009827_Vertical_Alignment_of_an_Inline_Graphic.html):

> The effect that Robert is noticing is the default behavior for inline graphics, although the cause he cites is backwards—it is actually the graphic that defaults to bottom alignment with the text, not the text with the graphic. So the solution involves adjusting the vertical positioning of the graphic.
>
> Word treats inline graphics as a single character. You can change the vertical alignment of an inline graphic by treating it as you would any other single character whose vertical position you wanted to adjust. Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Select the inline graphic by clicking on it once.
> 2. Display the Font dialog box.
>
>    - **NOTE**: Normally you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but when an image is selected this will duplicate instead.  You can open the dialog by expanding the font ribbon box.
>        [image: Open Font Dialog]
> 3. Go to the Advanced Tab.
> 4. Using the Position drop-down list, choose Lowered.
>
>    - [image: Character Spacing - Position - Lowered]
> 5. Enter a value in the By box, to the right of the Position control, that represents the number of points by which you want to lower the graphic.
> 6. Click OK.
>
> You may need to play with the value entered in the By box (step 5) to get just the look you want. The value you use will depend on the size of the graphic whose position you are adjusting and the characteristics of the font used in the paragraph.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works, though it sucks that you have to manually enter the height of the image. Also Ctrl+D isn't the Font dialog box - it is duplicate.

Comment: This one works better for me. Ctrl+D works when text is selected but not image. Try Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: On Word for Mac, looks like Command+Shift+F doesn't work for images. As a workaround, rise the text following the steps above :)

Comment: In Word for Mac: 
select the image and e.g. empty space before or after the image and then Cmd + D

Comment: I have waited for this solution for so many years. Thank you!!!  Being able to type in "220 px" and have it align right to the top of the image is fantastic

Answer (score 10):

But if you put an image in the correct location, set it's **Text Wrapping** to `Square`, `Tight` or `Through` and make your way to the **Picture Position** settings, you can configure **Vertical Alignment** to be `Centered` relative to `Line`.

I think this is as close as you can hope to get for "built in" features - this does, however, do some *rather* strange things to the layout if there are lines directly above or below - so test it does what you expect first.

## Edit

Now at home, so here's the long Word 2007 version - with pictures!

As per [munnaBhai](https://superuser.com/questions/100932/how-to-align-image-same-as-text-in-word-2007/129866#129866)'s answer, you may wish to stick this in a template if you plan to use it a lot.

First, insert the image file in the location you wish to appear and then select it.

Next open the "Advanced Layout" window:
[image: How to open the "Advanced Layout" window]

Set the text wrapping to Tight, then switch to the picture position tab:
[image: Setting the text wrapping mode]

Make the image move with your text, vertically centred to the line and horizontally linked to the character before it.
[image: setting the correct position options]

Final result (this image isn't great quality, I've taken it from a screenshot from your question). It's not perfect, but it's as close as I think you can get with the built in Word functionality:
[image: the final result, almost vertically aligned as needed]

Comment: Yeah this doesn't really work - text flows around the image in a weird way.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing Text alignment in Paragraph.

I have no idea why it is put under Asian Typography.

[image: Paragraph]

Comment: Hmm I think that tab must only show up if you have some language option set. It is missing for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should give a try for borderless table. Create table with 1 row and 2 columns, remove borders, then align table cells to the center vertically.

You may remove any cell spacings if needed. 
Type MathType formula in first cell, then type `this is how I want to be` in second cell.

It should work with other objects like images.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing you can do is select the picture then choose `Text Wrapping` and change it to `In Front of Text`, then simply drag the image a tiny bit down.

Comment: Well, it is a solution to align a single image, but this is not the one I'm looking for

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is way for your problem in Word 2007. Besides what Wil said above - to do manually; you can create a templet with that particular formating for images, but then it will be applied to all images in that document.

May be use some other text editors, say TeX, LyX (LaTex type doc editor)