# Formatting Organic Molecules and Lists in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

This is the 2019 NSW HSC Chemistry Exam: https://educationstandards.nsw.edu.au/wps/wcm/connect/e9541cfe-0a5a-499c-9c25-ae06ffd3a2c0/2019-hsc-chemistry.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=ROOTWORKSPACE-e9541cfe-0a5a-499c-9c25-ae06ffd3a2c0-mVt82KS

I am trying to reproduce the format of the document in Microsoft Word (2016), and have had success with most parts.

However, I am unable to figure out how organic molecules are incorporated as text, especially the vertical connectors (covalent bonds) between atoms. See pages 2, 5, 7, 14 and 30 of the document. For example, 
this molecule on page 5:

[image: Molecule on page 5]

I have considered drawing the molecules in external software and importing them as images, but a further issue is that some of these are part of a list, such as the following two examples, on pages 2 and 7 respectively:
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 7]

Images in Word are aligned with text at the bottom as shown:

[image: Alignment is incorrect]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Perhaps Word is simply the wrong program to attempt this with?

Comment: Very fair point—I am aware Word has its limitations. However, I was hoping there may be a solution in the short term, before I learn a more powerful program.

Comment: [How to align image same as text in Word 2007?](https://superuser.com/q/100932/241386)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this layout using a table:

- create a table of two columns, bullet points / numbers / letters in first column and pictures in the second one
- select the whole table and in "layout" tab select "center left" alignment

[image]

- and finally remove the borders:

[image]